# Function for create a zoom limit for don't show Map data not yet available

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

Is there any way to create a zoom limit function because despite the use of `minZoom` and `maxZoom`doesn't work in:

```
      leaflet() %>%
        setView(lng = lng, lat = lat, zoom=17) %>%
             addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, options = m 
                 providerTileOptions(minZoom = 15, maxZoom = 100)) %>%
                 addLayersControl(options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE))
```

for not permit or the `setView` block the exhibition of satellite images in a zoom that `Map data not yet available`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minZoom` and `maxZoom` work fine for me, but in `leafet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = x, maxZoom = y)`.

Under Initializing Options: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/map_widget.html

Comment: Not yet the answer, because if you click in the + or - button you can violate the `minZoom`or `maxZoom` defined.

Comment: My repex here https://rpubs.com/sashimonoko/leafletzoom